# Should I expect POSIX to include getopt.h?

Tags: posix, getopt-long

According to [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/head.html), the POSIX library does not include `getopt.h`. However, I found this in `unistd.h`:

```
#ifdef  __USE_POSIX2
/* Get definitions and prototypes for functions to process the
   arguments in ARGV (ARGC of them, minus the program name) for
   options given in OPTS.  */
# define __need_getopt
# include <getopt.h>
#endif
```

Does this mean that `getopt.h` is implicitly included when you include `unistd.h`? I mean, is the code above something I should expect from all implementations of the unistd header file, or is it just something that is in my particular version? Also, is the `__USE_POSIX2` macro defined in POSIX.2 and onwards, or is it just for POSIX.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__USE_POSIX2` is an implementation detail of glibc; it corresponds to `_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 2` or `_XOPEN_SOURCE` being defined. These are also implied by `_GNU_SOURCE`, and are used implicitly unless strict ANSI mode is on. You are not supposed to define the __USE_ macros directly.

Since it corresponds to a value `>= 2`, it does apply to later versions. See the [feature_test_macros](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) manpage for further details.

Or, from the comments in features.h (the *internal* header - don't include directly - that takes care of all this):

```
/* These are defined by the user (or the compiler)
   to specify the desired environment:
...
   _POSIX_C_SOURCE  If ==1, like _POSIX_SOURCE; if >=2 add IEEE Std 1003.2;
            if >=199309L, add IEEE Std 1003.1b-1993;
            if >=199506L, add IEEE Std 1003.1c-1995;
            if >=200112L, all of IEEE 1003.1-2004
            if >=200809L, all of IEEE 1003.1-2008
   _XOPEN_SOURCE    Includes POSIX and XPG things.  Set to 500 if
            Single Unix conformance is wanted, to 600 for the
            sixth revision, to 700 for the seventh revision.
```

Answer (score 1):

`getopt.h` is not mentioned in the `getopt(3)` man page. If you need `getopt`, you should include `unistd.h` and define (assuming GLIBC) `_XOPEN_SOURCE` or `_POSIX_C_SOURCE=something_greater_than_2` and not worry about the implementation details of the C library. Other environments might have different ways of turning on/off POSIX features.

Note that your tags imply the use of `getopt_long`. This is a GNU extension, and thus not portable.